# Numbers - date cell set to last day of the month

Tags: numbers

I have a Numbers sheet that I use to forecast the monthly interest payments on my mortgage and it's working well. The only issue is that the date cells auto-sets to the first day of the month.

Is there any way that I can make a cell automatically set to the last day in the month?

Answer (score 7):

Might [EOMONTH](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH659?viewlocale=en_US) work for you?

The EOMONTH function returns a date that is the last day of the month some number of months before or after a given date.

Example: **=EOMONTH("2/01/2015", 0)** returns: **Feb 28, 2015**

Answer (score 1):

Let us say the current date is in cell A192 and is 21 January 2017. You can  insert the eomonth date in another cell with

```
eomonth(A192,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but the answer to have a single field always show the last day of the month for me is

```
=EOMONTH(TODAY, 0)
```